# How do I call my ChatMessages() function in my scaffold?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So i want to call my ChatMessages() in my scaffold, however I do not know where to call it without getting an error, here is my ChatMessages() function;

```
    Widget chatMessages() {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: messageStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return snapshot.hasData
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
              return Text(ds["message"]);
            })
        : Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
  },
);
```

then here is my scaffold;

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.chatWithUsername),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Spacer(),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.attach_file),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20 * 0.75),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.05),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20 / 4,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                    controller: TextEditingController(),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Send a message",
                        border: InputBorder.none),
                  )),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.send,
                    color: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .bodyText1
                        .color
                        .withOpacity(0.64),
                  ),
                ],
```

Where can I implement the Chatmessages() within the scaffold to receive the data? For context I am adding messaging functionality to my app and this seems like a very easy fix however I cant figure it out :')

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I dont know why I said i'm getting an error, I want to retrieve and show chatmessages, however I'm not sure how to implement it into the scaffold

Comment: Putting chatMessages() in the Column of your Scaffold's body doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you'll need to have the following layout in your build function:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    child: SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<String>(),
            ),
            MessageEntryWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

should be something like this then:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    child: SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('chatWithUsername'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<String>(
                  stream: messageStream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: itemCount,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        //DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                        return Text('message');
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 4),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.attach_file),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20 * 0.75),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.05),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20 / 4,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: TextEditingController(),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: 'Send a message',
                                    border: InputBorder.none),
                              )),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.send,
                            color: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .bodyText1
                                ?.color
                                ?.withOpacity(0.64) ??
                                Colors.red,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Wrap the ListView.builder in the StreamBuilder you have ...

Comment: I have my new code, it's too long to reply with though. Sorry I'm new to posting on stack, so how do I show you the updated @kazume

Comment: You could make gist on github?

Comment: Nice this works! So now for some reason I couldn't add in the circularproggress indicator, Also when I go to type a message now, the message box just stays at the bottom and can't see what you are typing. Updated : https://gist.github.com/harrieanderson/fdf8b5cdeb8a4112b94ce067c322a893

Comment: Ah yeah, I see ... that's not good. Lemme fix that for you

Comment: I ditched the bottom nav bar approach for a Column with the listview expanding to the message entry widget at the bottom. How does that work for you?

Comment: As for the circular progress indicator, I'm not a huge fan of those anyway. They tend to stutter more often than not. If you want it in though, just check for the streambuilder's snapshot.data being null and return the ProgressIndicator if null, the ListView if not null. Also, giving your streambuilder the actual type it returns (instead of 'dynamic', unless you don't know the type of course) is better practice.

Comment: Nice man this all works, thank you so much. Can I add you on Discord or something? Would love to learn more from you